# modify global variable with function in another file

Tags: python

I am trying to modify a global variable by passing it to a function in another file, but it doesn't work:

File one:

```
from file_two import changeVar

globalVar = "none"

while True:
    move = input("enter command: ").lower().split() 
    if move[0] == "change":
        changeVar(globalVar)
        print(globalVar)
```

File two:

```
def changeVar(globalVar):
    globalVar = "some"
```

I tried using global in my function and I couldn't get that to work either. I have also read that creating a third file just to host the global variables may work, but that seems less than ideal. Whats more confusing is that one of the functions in my function file actually does appear to update a global variable in the main file.

Am I taking the wrong approach to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the function in File two to return `globalVar`, and then assign the output of the function to a variable in File one.

File 1:

```
while True:
    move = input("enter command: ").lower().split() 
    if move[0] == "change":
        globalVar = changeVar(globalVar)
        print(globalVar)
```

File 2:

```
def changeVar(globalVar):
    globalVar = "some"
    return globalVar
```

Comment: Cool, that works, but the issue I have now is that I am trying to modify multiple variables with the same function. How might I achieve that?

Comment: You likely need to pass all the variables you want to modify to the function, modify the variables, and then return all of them. And when you call the function, you just define all the modified variables, like `var1_mod, var2_mod, var3_mod = modify_function(var1, var2, var3)`. You could also pass a single variable that is a list of other variables, then go through the variables in the list inside your function, append them to a new list, and return the modified list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I would up putting two of the three object variables I am working with 'into' the third object as attributes, then I pass that to the  function. When I get the third object back I update the other two object variables with the modified attributes.